# Treating bootstrap nodes as any other node in private ethereum network

Tags: bootstrap

I'm chasing a problem which requires me to deploy a private Ethereum network. I was wondering if it is absolutely necessary to add dedicated bootstrap nodes whose sole purpose is to aid in peer discovery, or can I make it a bootstrap node, and also make it participate in storing the blockchain and/or block validation for PoS? I don't want to bring up extra nodes to keep the cost within bound.

Also, looking at the materials I found online, I understand these nodes have to be always available. But it's not clear, if I have multiple such nodes, is it required for all of them to be available, or is it fine if at-least one of them is reachable at any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an existing [geth node as a node+bootnode](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#creating-the-rendezvous-point), just pass the bootnode parameters (nodekey) to the geth command when you start it up.

All bootnodes need not be online at all times. A new node must be able to reach *at least* one bootnode. Once it has collected an initial list of peers, it will be able to ask them for new peers as well, and will function even without bootnodes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Can you please shade some light on the 2nd part of my question, if possible?

Comment: @Bitswazsky Apologies, I've edited my answer